# Blank desktop Elementary OS

Tags: system-installation, graphic-drivers, ubuntu

i tried to do a full installation on a 16 gb usb,
but something went wrong

the os is stuck after the logo with the cursor (movable) on a black screen or (if I press enter twice) a picture of a tree branch and nothing else https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJUHf.jpg

the exact same thing happens even in live usb 'try elementary'' mode.

I believe it's the graphic card, either with nomodeset on or recovery mode everything loads (in low resolution with the first) 
in recovery mode I have installed intel microcode in drivers with no effect

Answer (score 1):

Does it load after a while (1/2 minutes)?
If yes, you're facing a bug in dbus like I did.

Workaround:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop.backup
```

More info: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1596377 or https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2016-July/msg02793.html

Comment: No.In normal mode it doesn't load at all, loads normally only with nomodeset on or in recovery mode